# Install Windows cmd in WINE

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe, wine

CMD implemented by WINE [struggle to run](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=32463) complex batch scripts, I think it is possible to overcome by installing CMD.exe from Windows, but upon executing anything in it gives different meaningless error messages like this:

```
Message 0x2350 not found in file Application.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Windows cmd.exe is built into Windows and not (so far as I know) exportable to another OS.  Try a 3rd party command processor.   ........  https://www.makeuseof.com/best-command-prompt-alternatives-for-windows/

Comment: It's terminal emulators, not batch interpreters, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the end I took cmd from [ReactOS](https://reactos.org/) and it worked well

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).